# Parallel function for parsing PDF in R with if/else statement

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have a series of PDFs that are 50 pages each. I wrote the following code to go through each PDF and extract tables. I only need tables that are 12 columns long; any tables that are 5 columns long should be discarded.

I would like to use doParallel to speed up this process as it's quite slow. However, I can't figure out how to write the parallelization code, while still retaining the if/else statement that skips tables that are not 12 columns long. Any ideas?

```
parse_pdf = function(file) {
  pdf_scrape = extract_tables(file=str_c("./data/output/", file))
  print(paste0("tables extracted for file ", file)
  return(pdf_scrape)
}

filelist = list.files("./data/output")

big_df = data.frame()

for(file in filelist) {
  pdf_scrape = parse_pdf(file)

  for(i in 1:length(pdf_scrape)) {
    df = as_tibble(pdf_scrape[[i]])
    number_of_columns = ncol(pdf_scrape[[i]])
    if(number_of_columns==12) {
      big_df = rbind(big_df, df)
    } else {print(paste0("page ",i," was discarded"))}
  }
  print(paste0("finished with: ", file))
}
```